# Type Safety warning when trying to avoid returning NULL

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

In Eclipe, Java, I'm working on a method that does a bunch of stuff and at the end needs to return a generated list with argument Element. It is possible that this list is null in which case I want the method to return an empty list. This is to prevent needing `if(list != null)` checks everywhere since for statements work with empty lists.

I do this in the following way:

```
return tempList == null ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : tempList;
```

This however gives the following warning :

> Type Safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to comfirm to `List<Element>`.

All the solutions Eclipse suggest don't work. I'm guessing the problem is with `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` returning a generic list, but have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this syntax if you really want to avoid local variable declaration.

```
return elements == null ? Collections.<Element>emptyList() : elements;
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Collections.emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) for an empty, type-safe, and immutable list.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick if I do the following:

List<Element> emptyList = Collections.emptyList();
return tempList == null ? emptyList : tempList;

Guessing it is not possible to avoid the local variable, since you need to know the type.

Comment: Since you have two lines now anyway, I would do it as `if(tempList == null) tempList = Collections.emptyList();`

Answer (score 0):

Why not you just return `new ArrayList<Element>()` ?

Comment: It depends on how client will use returned list. If client code will modified it (add for example), then return a new list is the only way to go. If not, then Collections.emptyList() is more readable, and reduce unnecessary new object created.